# jQuery load() keeping previous elements in memory?

Tags: jquery

I have an element, into which I load...

```
$("#pending").load("/pages/tipping/add-tips.php?pending=1&tip_comp=1");
```

Whenever a radio button is checked, that is re-loaded...

```
$(".comp_id").on("click",function(){
    var compID=$(this).val();
    $("#pending").load("/pages/tipping/add-tips.php?pending=1&tip_comp="+compID);
});
```

Inside this loaded content are inputs, which upon clicking a link I cycle through these inputs...

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("input.stake").each(function(){
        alert("TEST");
    });
});
```

However, every time the content is re-loaded, it seems to "remember" the previous loads. For example, say there is 1 input to cycle through, upon loading the page the first time, I get 1 alert.

If I then change the input, and submit, I get 2 alerts, then 3 etc etc. Despite there only actually being one input there the whole time.

What's causing this, and what's the solution? It's dricving me a little crazy.

EDIT:

So if I cycle through the inputs from outside the file, it knows that there is only 1. It's ONLY when the cycle is done from within the loaded content, that it thinks there is more than 1.

Thanks

Comment: If every loaded content has an input and you perform a .each selecting those inputs then yes it will increase every time you perform the load and add more inputs to your DOM

Comment: Could you show what the loaded content looks like?

Comment: It's complicated and hard to show to be honest...

However, when reloaded, there is just 1 input, yet if I click the radiobox, say 3 times, I will get a cycle of 3 inputs. Despite as I say, there only being 1 input...

Comment: **SOLVED**

Putting the Query outside the loaded div worked.

Answer (score 0):

`.load` just adds content to the target element.  You could use `.get` if you want to replace it:

```
$.get("/pages/tipping/add-tips.php?pending=1&tip_comp="+compID, function(data) {
     $("#pending").replaceWith(data);
});
```

Comment: I didn't realise .load just adds content, because actually it was reloading it.

Comment: I tried this solution, and the same thing is still happening - I put .html(data) instead of replaceWith(data)

Comment: `.load()` is just shorthand for `.get()` followed by `.html(data)`.

Comment: Actually this seems to have potential, but it's not passing the compID variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".comp_id").on("click",function(){
    var compID=$(this).val();
    $("#pending").load("/pages/tipping/add-tips.php?pending=1&tip_comp="+compID);
});
```

This will get executed on each click. One workaround might be, remove existing inputs and load again

```
 $(".comp_id").on("click",function(){
            var compID=$(this).val();

            $("input.stake").each(function(){
                $(this).remove();
               });

            $("#pending").load("/pages/tipping/add-tips.php?pending=1&tip_comp="+compID);
        });
```

Comment: `.load()` automatically empties the DIV before loading into it, there's no need to do that explicitly.

Comment: So why then, is it cycling through more inputs than actually exist?

Comment: Is there any way to clear what's obviously still somewhere, before loading again?

Comment: or Can you try .remove() on existing inputs?

Comment: This is strange. .remove()  removes the element from DOM, not sure how it's coming up in your code. I just tried some sample code at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vaugq3g/). After remove call, ideally inputs should be gone

Comment: I took the jQuery code from the loaded div and put it in the main page.

Sometimes I forget that the browser loads all this, so it doesn't matter where the jS is!